# Ansible condition - Multiple host

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I am writing Ansible playbook wherein I need to use below condition, if condition is failing then playbook execution should stop for all the hosts.

Condition - specific file should be present in all the hosts

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please, correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `any_errors_fatal` option to abort the play when a task fails on one of the hosts.

```
 - hosts: all
   tasks:
     - name: check file presence
       block:
         - name: check for file
           stat: path=/tmp/myspecialfile
           register: myspecialfile
         - name: fail when not present
           fail: msg='File is not present on host'
           when: not myspecialfile.stat.exists
       any_errors_fatal: true
```

See these [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#aborting-the-play)